# Set default sending account on a contact by contact basis in OS X mail

Tags: mail.app

I have several different mail accounts setup in Mail. Is it possible to define which account to use on a contact by contact basis? I'm trying to avoid sending mail from the wrong account, to the wrong person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love to see this feature in Mail (because I would likely use it a lot), but this currently isn't supported.